# Creating an alias with grep command that contains single quotes

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, jq

I am trying to alias the following:

```
jq | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^"]+'
```

However when I use:

```
alias xxx="jq | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^"]+'"
```

*I get an error :S*

Is there a way I can create an alias with that?

Any help would be very much appreciated - thanks for your time :)

Comment: What do you need grep for?

Comment: To quote the manual: `For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions`.  With a function, this is trivial.

Comment: Note that the documentation has stated this about aliases since at least 1996.

Comment: @oguzismail I am piping a JSON output to this alias. I'm sorry William I am still learning.

Answer (score 1):

The alias body has a quote (in [^"], which must be escaped, otherwise it will terminate the quotes that opens the body.

```
alias xxx="jq | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^\"]+'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Under most circumstances, if you're going to use jq at all, it would probably be better to use jq to do the string-matching as well.  Assuming you're not interested in key names that happen to look like URLs, you could consider using something like the following:

```
function xxx {
 jq -r '.. | strings | capture("(?<x>(http|https)://[^\"]+)") | .x'
}
```